# How to have user pick up where they left off on react-hook-form using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

There are 7 pages a user of our application needs to go through to fill out all respective information for their profile. When the user logs out in the middle of filling out this information, everything is saved; however, when they log back in, they are sent to the first page of the form instead of the page they left off on.

We are using Typescript and the form is built using react-hook-form and react-router-dom. Our Routes are set up as below:

```
        <Route
          path={PrivateRoutes.PROFILE_SETUP}
          element={<GeneralPartnerProfileSetup />}
        >
          <Route
            path={PrivateRoutes.FIRM_OVERVIEW}
            element={<FirmOverview />}
          />
          <Route
            path={PrivateRoutes.FUND_OVERVIEW}
            element={<FundOverview />}
          />
          <Route
            path={PrivateRoutes.PAST_PERFORMANCE}
            element={<PastPerformance />}
          />
          <Route
            path={PrivateRoutes.INVESTMENT_TEAM}
            element={<InvestmentTeam />}
          />
          <Route path={PrivateRoutes.FUND_DETAILS} element={<FunDetails />} />
          <Route
            path={PrivateRoutes.FUND_STRUCTURE}
            element={<FundStructure />}
          />
          <Route
            path={PrivateRoutes.REVIEW_AND_SUBMIT}
            element={<ReviewAndSubmit />}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route
          path={PrivateRoutes.PROFILE_UPDATE}
          element={<ProfileUpdate />}
        />
      </Route>
```

I've tried searching for examples to add a way to track the state but I seem to keep coming up short. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include ***all relevant*** code you are working with as part of a more complete [mcve]? The routes alone are not the issue. Can you share where/how you determine what "step" a user is on? How the user data is initialized and updated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.